# I'm trying to curl a GET request

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-api-gateway

I'm quite new to openstack and software development, but here goes.
i'm trying to curl a GET request via AWS Api Gateway.

the curl looks like this:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i GET -d 'name=Claus&username=gettest&password=test' https://xy8fbbpvak.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/adduser
```

but it gives me this response:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 43
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 06:10:08 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: c049f3e5-6b7f-11e7-a380-d966a8908f27
x-amzn-ErrorType: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 dc81da318a4ae20e51ccfd9463219596.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: BI3LX_cwBic2EtCleIHd6yT0B1p4GRoqEbqx85L1nO2UUafPKXC2iQ==

{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

The method in AWS API Gateway doesn't need authorization or a token.

I'm really not sure what i'm doing wrong? please tell me if you need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` does not necessarily means that it needs an authorization or a token, but you receive the same error if you request a URL that doesn't exist

You need to make sure you're using the correct HTTP method and resource path to a valid resource.

From your example, you're using a `GET` and the action is `prod/adduser`, that does not sound too good to me, addUser would generally be made on `PUT` or `POST` when you design your API.

Also make sure to deploy your API changes, when you test from the API gateway, its a staging area but its not deployed

Comment: Thank you for the answer! i'm just not quite sure on how to set the correct resource path then though. i already made the POST request, which worked just fine.

Comment: and you're sure you have a GET method on addUser resource ?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure.

Comment: ah i figured it out! I was all wrong. the correct curl was:
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'https://xy8fbbpvak.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/adduser?{name=Claus&username=testGET&password=test}'